# example to disable code in templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I want to disable a line of code(set of lines of code) in a function, if my template is of particular type, and if not it should be enabled.. 
please help

```
typename<T>::foo()
{
....
//if the T is type int 
i = i+1;
.....
}
```

Comment: I have checked the example present in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986125/disabling-hiding-functions-in-a-template-based-on-compile-time-constants but it is for a function... i want a method to disable particular line of code

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, you might use if constexpr:

```
typename<T>::foo()
{
    //....
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        i = i+1;
    }
    //.....
}
```

Comment: thanks... but this works only in c++ 17.. is there any other way....